# 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" when using where not exists in my statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have below SQL syntax trying to find out the records that are present in myTable1 and not in myTable2. (My original SQL is pretty complex and I have to use the 'where not exists' condition to eliminate records from my results.)

`select col1 as column1, col2 as column2 from myTable1 tbl1 where not exists (select col1 as columnA, col3 as columnB from myTable2 tbl2 where tbl1.col1 = tbl2.col1 );`

But my Oracle SQLdeveloper keeps throwing me the error -

```
 ORA-00904: "TBL1"."COL1": invalid identifier
 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

I replaced COL1 with the alias name TBL1.COLUMN1 and it still throws me the same error on that column. Can you help me figure out how to fix this error? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This error *usually* means that there's no such column in that table. Did you misspell it? Is it created using mixed letter case under double quotes? Could you post tables' description? Because, query we see looks OK.

---

Apart from that, did you consider using *sets*? Something like this:

```
select col1, col2 from mytable1
minus
select col1, col3 from mytable2;
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not misspell my column names, and yes, it is created using a mixed letter case. I went back and corrected the case of my letters, and I was able to get the results. Also, the MINUS suggestion looks useful, but can I have a condition (where clause) at the end of the MINUS clause? I want to give you a thumbs-up for your answer, but I don't have enough reputations.

Comment: You can put WHERE clause into each of these SELECT statements. Or, you can use (what I posted) as a CTE or an inline view, and then apply WHERE to the result.